# Connecting to Sybase DB using Squirrel SQL Client - Driver Class not found Exception

Tags: java, sybase, squirrel-sql

I am currently trying to connect to a Sybase DB using Squirrel Client.  However, when I try to connect I am getting an error with the following stack trace.

java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sybase.jdbc2.jdbc.SybDriver

After seeing similiar questions on here, I downloaded the JTDS 1.3.1 driver (everything I'm seeing is saying that that is the appropriate driver for sybase) and added the jar file to the lib folder in my squirrel installation.  The error is still showing.

The format for my URL is jdbc:sybase:Tds:host:port/DBNAME

If anyone has any ideas, I would appreciate the help, I'm drawing all kinds of blanks here.

Comment: If you're getting this error, you're are not seeing the driver. Check the jar spelling. Try setting the CLASSLIB env variable to include the jar as well. Lastly, check the jar itself, if it does contain that class, since it may have a different JDBC driver version number.

Comment: Did you ever fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Sybase ASE here; Sybase ASA and ASIQ might be different.

- Host should be the host name or IP address of the host running the Sybase instance.
- Port is the TCP IP Port number of the "dataserver" process. This is possibly 4100 (Unix) or 5000 (Windows), but can be overridden by the person who installed the Sybase ASE database server
- DBNAME is the name of the database you want to connect to. Try "tempdb" if you're unsure.

If Sybase ASE is running on your Windows PC, the settings might be as follows:

```
jdbc:sybase:Tds:localhost:5000/tempdb
```

or on some other Unix database server:

```
jdbc:sybase:Tds:dataserver_name:4100/tempdb
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to connect to Sybase Adaptive Server Enterprise using squirrel sql 4.2.0 (so that it will work with jvm 1.8).
First, I installed a trial version of Aqua Data Studio 23.0,
then i got the sybase enterprise driver from that installation:

```
C:\Program Files\Aqua Data Studio 23.0 - 64bit\lib\drivers\jconnect16.jar
```

Then I followed this tutorial:
https://blogs.sap.com/2016/06/28/how-to-configure-squirrel-to-use-it-with-sap-ase/

and used the following Class Name:

```
com.sybase.jdbc42.jdbc.SybDriver
```